# Parallel processing in F#

Tags: concurrency, f#

I'm playing around with `async` in F#. Does this look right, or am I mangling things?

```
let time f = 
    let before = System.DateTime.Now
    f () |> ignore
    let after = System.DateTime.Now
    after - before;;

let rec fib = function 0 | 1 -> 1
                         | n -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2);;

let source = [45; 40; 45; 40]

let synchronous = time <| fun () -> List.map fib source

let para = time <| fun () -> source
                             |> List.map (fun n -> async {ignore <| fib n}) 
                             |> Async.Parallel
                             |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

In particular, how do I return results from an `async` block? Do I have to use mutable state?

**Update:** here's another approach:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq.dll"
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections

let pseq = time <| fun () -> source
                             |> PSeq.map fib
                             |> PSeq.toList
```

Comment: Maybe this is a fit for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: ildjarn what about `let foo = async {3 + 4}`. It gives warning FS0020: `3 + 4` should have type unit.

Comment: @Rosarch : `let foo = async { return (3 + 4) }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, it's a bit of an anti-pattern to use `async` for parallel CPU processing. See these questions and answers for more information:

[Why shouldn't I use F# asynchronous workflows for parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327591/why-shouldnt-i-use-f-asynchronous-workflows-for-parallelism)

[Task Parallel Library vs Async Workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871168/f-task-parallel-library-vs-async-workflows)

Secondly, your `fib` function should be re-written to be tail recursive, here's an example from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Solutions/Recursion) (including changing to `BigInt`):

```
let fib n =
    let rec loop acc1 acc2 = function
        | n when n = 0I -> acc1
        | n -> loop acc2 (acc1 + acc2) (n - 1I)
    loop 0I 1I n
```

Finally, the full code:

```
let source = [| 45I; 40I; 45I; 40I |]

let sync = time <| fun () -> Array.map fib source

let para = time <| fun () -> Array.Parallel.map fib source
```

Note that in both cases an `Array` of the results is returned, you're just throwing it away in your time function. How about a `time` function that returns both the time and the result?

```
let time f = 
    let watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    watch.Start()
    let res = f ()
    watch.Stop()
    (res, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

Usage remains the same, but now showing results:

```
printfn "Sync: %A in %ims" (fst sync) (snd sync)
printfn "Para: %A in %ims" (fst para) (snd para)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just throwing away the result because I didn't care about the computation; just how long it took. What about using PSeq from the F# Power Pack?

Comment: Sure, you could use that if you had anything more complex then `map` to do. As it stands, what we've got here is the most efficient for your particular problem. Further reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851745/does-f-async-parallel-speed-up-calculations (second answer by Tomas, and the linked blog also).